# transcendence basis of field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

In some exercice, I see the following:

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(X_1 ,\dots , X_n )$ and $k = \mathbb{Q}(e_1 , \dots, e_n )$, where $(e_i)$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials.

It states:

"Since K is a finite extension, it is algebraic over k, therefore K and k have the same transcendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$."

I see no such result in my course, and the closest thing I found is this result:

since K is finite, therefore algebraic over k, the family $S=(e_1 , \dots , e_n )$ contains a transcendence basis of K over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Could you please help me find the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Take some transcendence basis of $k$. Since $K/k$ is algebraic, it's also a transcendence basis of $K$.

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to understand why algebraically independent elements of the transcendance basis remain   algebraically independent in an algebraic extension K

Comment: That's because in both cases what you are considering is algebraic independence *over $\mathbb Q$*. Enlarging the field won't introduce more algebraic relations with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ of elements of an extension field $k/F$ is a transcendency basis if

1. there is no nonzero polynomial $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in F[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ such that $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)=0$;
2. $k$ is algebraic over $F(t_1,\dots,t_n)$.

Note that condition 1 implies that every $t_i$ is transcendental over $F$ (but it is stronger than this).

It follows that if $K$ is an algebraic extension of $k$, then $\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ is also a transcendency basis of $K$ over $F$, because the elements are still algebraically independent and $K$ is algebraic over $F(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ (algebraic over algebraic).

Condition 1 is usually expressed by saying that $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are algebraically independent. For infinite sets, substitute condition 1 with “every finite subset is algebraically independent”.

Comment: Actually i have a difficulty with condition 1): why does $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are algebraically independent over F imply   $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are algebraically independent over k, there are more polynomial in k that may verify $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)=0$ and $f\ne 0$?

Comment: @PerelMan Nobody is saying that the elements are algebraically independent over $k$, because they aren't. I'll add a clause to clarify.