# Is every element of $\mathbb{R}$ a member of $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoined with finitely many members of its transcendence basis?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Recently I've been interested in creating somewhat non-constructive solutions to problems using the concept of a *transcendence basis* of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which exists assuming the Axiom of Choice but I only know some basic Field Theory. As part of my increasing understanding, I ask:

Let $W$ be the transcendence basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. **Is it true that $$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{w\subset W, \;w \text{ finite}}\mathbb{Q}(w)$$? What if we replace "finite" with "countable"?**

Comment: If $W$ is a transcendence basis then the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(W)$ is that union. As Andreas Caranti explained, this is a long way from being all of $\Bbb{R}$. It won't even contain all the transcendentals. If you, for example, replace $W$ with the set $W^{1/3}$ of cube roots of the elements of $W$ (unique in $\Bbb{R}$), you get a bigger field $\Bbb{Q}(W^{1/3})$ that is an infinite extension of $\Bbb{Q}(W)$ and still contains only rationals and transcentals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but, quoting for instance from [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3054270/58401):

> a set $T$ of elements of an extension field $k/F$ is a *transcendence* basis if
>
> 1. for all $n$, and distinct $t_{1}, \dots, t_{n} \in T$, there is no nonzero polynomial $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in F[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ such that $f(t_1,\dots,t_n)=0$;
> 2. $k$ is algebraic over $F(T)$.

So an element like $\sqrt{2}$ will not be in any of your $\mathbb{Q}(w)$.

Comment: Ah but polynomials are finite in length, right? So does it work with countable subsets? And if we were to replace $\mathbb{Q}$ (the "starting field") with the algebraic numbers, can we get around this and still have finite numbers?

Comment: I have removed my previous comment, which was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**. This answer is incorrect. I read "transcendence basis" as "vector space basis". I think @AndreasCaranti 's answer is correct. I will leave mine up so no one else makes the same mistake.

---

Yes, since every element of $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of basis elements. That means it's in the union of the corresponding extensions.

Comment: So to be clear, that's part of the definition of the basis? That everything in particular is a finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination?

Comment: This is wrong. You're confusing a basis as a vector space with a transcendence basis.

Comment: @KReiser I was editing my answer while you were commenting.